# What Android View element should be used for a Multi-tiered Filter?

Tags: android

The use case:

I need the user to select items, in a list or treeview styled element.
The items are in multi-tiered categories / headers.

Example:

Cars

-> Wheels

---> Mags

-----> **Chrome**

-----> **Matte black**

-----> **Silver**

---> Tyres

-----> **Outdoor**

-----> Indoor

-------> **Racing**

-------> **Ordinary**

---> Paint

-----> **Red**

-----> **Blue**

So only those in bold are selectable.

I thought a `multi-level expandable listview` would be good but it is not a native control.

What is the best `View` for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

`Expandable listview` will get you to a completed solution the quickest. You should make your own adapter that dynamically handles adding in the different tiers to the other individual `expandable listviews`. Sadly though, this solution sounds very messy and cumbersome. Check out ["Android Arsenal"](https://android-arsenal.com) Someone may have made a library that does exactly this already. That website is a decent start.